# Does SQLiteConnection.BeginTransaction retry when database is locked?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm using SQLite (System.Data.SQLite.dll) in a multi-threaded Windows desktop program. I use this code:

```
using (var cn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (var tx = cn.BeginTransaction())
    {
          // do some work here

         tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

I'm stressing the program using 8 concurrent threads writing to the database at the same time. Sometimes I see this message on the Visual Studio output window:

```
SQLite error (517): statement aborts at 1: [BEGIN IMMEDIATE] database is locked
```

But no exception is thrown at all, and everything works as expected. So I guess SQLConnection.BeginTrasaction() retries when it receives SQLite error (517) database is locked.

Am I right?

If yes, how many times SQLConnection.BeginTransaction retries before throwing an exception. Is this configurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is handled by [BUSY TIMEOUT](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout):

> PRAGMA busy_timeout;
> PRAGMA busy_timeout = milliseconds;
>
> Query or change the setting of the busy timeout. This pragma is an
> alternative to the sqlite3_busy_timeout() C-language interface which
> is made available as a pragma for use with language bindings that do
> not provide direct access to sqlite3_busy_timeout().
>
> Each database connection can only have a single busy handler. This
> PRAGMA sets the busy handler for the process, possibly overwriting any
> previously set busy handler.

The timeout interval is defined by default to 30 seconds in `SQLite.dll`. Turns out you can't change that, only via invoking the unsafe C function.

From the [SQLite C Interface](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html):

> int sqlite3_busy_timeout(sqlite3*, int ms);
>
> Calling this routine with an argument less than or equal to zero turns off all busy handlers.

Comment: Thanks, that explains things

Comment: What happened with BusyTimout property? Will it be in the next version of System.Data.SQLite?.  PRAGMA busy_timeout returns 0 in my program . What is going on here? Does System.Data.SQLite use sqlite3_busy_handler https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html?

Comment: Turns out it isn't declared inside Sqlite.dll. It was in another open source library. Seems like you cant explicitly set it at all :/

Answer (score 3):

I finally found it digging into the source code of System.Data.SQLite.dll.

SQLite3.Prepare method (wich is called before executing any command) has the following code in it:

```
while ((n == SQLiteErrorCode.Schema || n == SQLiteErrorCode.Locked || n == SQLiteErrorCode.Busy) && retries < 3)
{
  try
  ...
```

So, System.Data.SQLite will retry any command up to 3 times before throwing an exception.

EDIT:

SQLite3.Prepare method has this interesting piece of code which is self-explanatory:

```
  else if (n == SQLiteErrorCode.Locked || n == SQLiteErrorCode.Busy) // Locked -- delay a small amount before retrying
  {
    // Keep trying
    if (rnd == null) // First time we've encountered the lock
      rnd = new Random();

    // If we've exceeded the command's timeout, give up and throw an error
    if ((uint)Environment.TickCount - starttick > timeoutMS)
    {
      throw new SQLiteException(n, GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
      // Otherwise sleep for a random amount of time up to 150ms
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1, 150));
    }
  }
```

Note that locked and busy erros don't increment retries counter, so Prepare method will keep retrying until command timeout expires.

I created a ticket asking for max number of retries be configurable:

[Configurable number of retries and sleep time of SQLite3.Prepare](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/647d282d111f6c3638138809df5ea8ae8dd900ae)